# SO's [final] tag is used in non-java tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

SO's tag [final](/questions/tagged/final) is [defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/final) as

> final is a java keyword specifying that the reference declared as final cannot be modified once initialized

However, some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/final+php) related to php are tagged with the said tag. I'm thinking of these following options.

1. Changing the tag's definition to include php (or other language that has [final](/questions/tagged/final) keyword)
2. Creating a tag name [final-java](/questions/tagged/final-java) and [final-php](/questions/tagged/final-php). Placing [final](/questions/tagged/final) at the start so that in tag intellisense, the [final](/questions/tagged/final) word will appear and then the language.
3. No change.

What do you think?

*Update*

It's [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/342316)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would propose that the existing tag wiki be broadened to discuss the use of this keyword in the several languages in which it appears. Tags like [final-java](/questions/tagged/final-java) are quite ugly in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm, yeah the mere existence of [tag:java] or [tag:php] will disambiguate the [tag:final] tag in questions with related to it.